# Difference between Attack Boost, Damage Boost, and Demolition Boost in Valkyria Chronicles?

Tags: valkyria-chronicles

In Valkyria Chronicles (PS3) does the increase in damage make up for the additional CP?

Say I have 5 CP to take out a tank. I could do:

- Attack Boost for 1 CP
- 4 CP of basic boost attacks

or

- Damage Boost for 2 CP
- 3 CP of medium boost attacks

or

- Demolition Boost for 3 CP
- 2 CP of high boost attacks

Does sacrificing an attack for an additional boost make up for it? Which boost is the optimal?

Comment: It's been several years since I've played it, but my fuzzy recollection seems to tell me that Attack is actually Accuracy.  Demolition is for Lancers, I believe, so that their rockets do more damage.  But, really, you shouldn't need that due to always nailing their weakpoint, anyways.

Comment: Accuracy Boost is for Accuracy, Attack Boost is damage increase. And there's certain tank bosses that are more complex then just blowing up their weak point. @Frank

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Attack Boost only increases your anti-personnel attack power; it does not affect damage against tanks.

Taken from [a thread in the Steam Forum](http://steamcommunity.com/app/294860/discussions/0/624074858788389767/):

- Damage Boost order increases your vsArmor by 50.
- Demolition Boost order increases your vsArmor by 100.

For lancers, those bonuses are usually not very useful, since lancers deal multiple hundreds of damage to tanks from the beginning of the game (according to the [VC wiki](http://valkyria.wikia.com/wiki/Lances_(VC1)), the lances you start the game with already deal 850 damage vsArmor, minus the respective tank's defense value). As long as you have enough ammo, your lancers are better off attacking more often without these orders.

However, these orders can show great effect when used on Scouts, Engineers and especially Shocktroopers. I've had several games where I boosted Rosie with Demolition Boost and destroyed an enemy tank in a single move by going crazy on the tank's radiator with her machine gun (with every single shot being buffed by 100 vsArmor).

Another order to consider is the Penetration order, which lets you ignore the enemy's defense value. For your lancers, this should increase the damage dealt to tanks by a lot more than the Damage Boost or Demolition Boost would.